# How to change MongoDB slowOpThresholdMs in mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, profiler, mongodb-3.0

I need to decrease the slowms trash hold to 50, can't find the way of doing that without restarting the mongod process.

Comment: can you tell your system.profile level that is '0' or '1'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `slowOpThresholdMs` setting defines what constitutes a “slow” operation. To set the threshold which the profiler considers operations “slow” (and thus, included in the `level 1 profiling data`), you can configure `slowOpThresholdMs` at runtime as an argument to the `db.setProfilingLevel()` operation.

For Ref [setProfilingLevel](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/#db.setProfilingLevel) and 
[slowOpThresholdMs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#operationProfiling.slowOpThresholdMs)

**Note:**  `The threshold for slow operations applies to the entire mongod instance. When you change the threshold, you change it for all databases on the instance.`

For Example:

```
{ profile: 1, slowms: 200 }
```

Database profiling can impact database performance. Enable this option only after careful consideration

Answer (score -2):

Try this: `db.setProfilingLevel( 1, 50)`

Comment: Always write down some statement along with syntax. What actually you want to do according with your parameter as well as your syntax.

Comment: Care to explain a bit what this does? Also I see it mentioned in the other answer so I'm not sure this really adds anything